# Adding a WCF IPC service to an existing App that access an SQLite DB through EntityFrameworkCore

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-core, servicehost

I'm looking for some help.

I have a Mono application for Mac, developed in VS for Mac, using the currently latest updates in the VS for Mac, which include Mono Framework MDK 5.16.0.221. The app is targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1

The app accesses an SQLite DB throught EF Core, all latest packages, the problem is that things brakes if I try to add a WCF service to the app. Apparently the order between the service start and the DB context initialization is making the app to crash.

I have created [this example project](https://github.com/ivancitin/EF_and_WCF), which include a test case for the issue.

It works fine as it is, but if the IPC initialization is done before the DB context (Moving [this line](https://github.com/ivancitin/EF_and_WCF/blob/master/Test/Test.cs#L44) to be after [this one](https://github.com/ivancitin/EF_and_WCF/blob/master/Test/Test.cs#L34)), the failure can be reproduce.

Edit:

The issue i have detected is the order between the WCF `ServiceHost` is started, and the initialization of the EF `DbContext` is affecting the application behavior.

Initializing the `ServiceHost` first:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(singletonInstance);

...

serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(S), new NetTcpBinding(), serviceAddress);
serviceHost.Open();
```

then the `DbContext`

```
var databaseProvider = new DatabaseProvider(DB_FILE);
DatabaseContext databaseContext = databaseProvider.GetConnection();
```

Results into an exception like **`System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.`**, when using the `databaseContext` to access information from the DB.

Thank you

Comment: it would help to extract the code lines that matter into the questions!

Comment: I suspect that it might be an old DLL in one of the projects that gets loaded, and so your application cant get a hold of the required method